# Adding a check of no related before posting a question

Tags: feature-request, asking-questions, related-questions

When a user is asking a question, he or she start to write title and list of related questions shows and so on.
When he or she add tags he or she will press the <kbd>Post Your Question</kbd>.

I think, If list of related question moves below of tags with adding a check (Box) like  <kbd>`[ ]` `No related question found`</kbd> before enabling <kbd>Post Your Question</kbd> button will reduce rate of growing duplicate questions.

Comment: I feel like this would be treated like “I have read and accepted the T&Cs”. People would check it, but it would have minimal effect on whether people actually looked for related questions.

Comment: @alexwlchan I think with this we can notify users about importance related questions more than current approach ;).